# SQL Server Trigger - Insert the deleted record into another table with deletetime

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, triggers

Currently I have a Item table and a ItemWaste table. 
Both tables will have some fields, such as: Name, Amount, etc. But the ItemWaste table will have one more field, which is the TimeWasted.
I wish to automatically insert the DELETED item from the Item table to the ItemWaste table, and at the same time insert the deletion time to the TimeWasted field.

I got no idea how to do this, is it using trigger???

Hope can get some help here... Appreciate any feedback... Thanks....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure - not a problem.

You need a basic `AFTER DELETE` trigger - something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_ItemDelete 
ON dbo.Item 
AFTER DELETE 
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.ItemWaste(Name, Amount, TimeWasted)
        SELECT d.Name, d.Amount, GETDATE()
        FROM Deleted d
```

That's all there is! One point to remember: the trigger is called **once per batch** - e.g. if you delete 100 rows at once, it will be called **once** and the pseudo table `Deleted` will contain 100 rows. The trigger is **not** called once per row (a common misconception).

Comment: Btw, I not really clear what you mean by once per batch, if i delete 3 rows, the deleted table will still have 3 rows rite?

Comment: @user834754: yes - if you have a SQL statement that deletes 3 rows - your trigger will be fired **once** but the `Deleted` pseudo table will contain 3 rows, and thus 3 rows are being inserted into your `ItemWaste` table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply by writting a trigger you can `insert` a row when an `delete` action is performed in another table, have a look at [Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)