# How can I use a trigger in SQL Server to delete a row from a table and at the same time the deleted row should be added to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

```sql
create trigger sampletrigger
on SunilkarDB.dbo.salesorder_table
for delete
as 
    insert into salesorderdel_table
```

I have a table called `salesorder`, I am creating a trigger such that when I delete a row from the `salesorder` table, the row here gets deleted and gets added to new table called `salesorderdel` table.

I have written the following code and its not working, please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Trigger - Insert the deleted record into another table with deletetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763369/sql-server-trigger-insert-the-deleted-record-into-another-table-with-deletetim)

Comment: You can use DELETED table as decribed in [Use the inserted and deleted tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the values that you want to insert in the table.  You can use the `deleted` logical table.

e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  sampletrigger ON SunilkarDB.dbo.salesorder_table

FOR  DELETE  
AS  
  
INSERT INTO  SunilkarDB.dbo.salesorder_table ( [Name])
SELECT [Name]
FROM deleted
```